# What accessories, aside from faucets, fit into sink faucet holes?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet, sink

I'm going to replace an existing 3-hole faucet with a single hole faucet in my kitchen sink.  I plan on installing a soap dispenser into one of the other holes, but that will still leave me with one empty hole.  Aside from faucets what accessories are available that fit into faucet holes?

Comment: Some [Dishwasher Air Gaps](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=dishwasher+air+gap&hl=en&newwindow=1&tbm=shop&cid=17114913271176013683) do.  Hint, hint. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most common I've seen.

- Sprayer.
- Soap/lotion dispenser.
- Filtered water faucet.
- A Plug to fill the unused hole.

Most single hole faucets come with an extra base piece that covers up the old unused holes.

Answer (score 3):

An instant hot water tap would also fit.   We have a long run to the hot water heater, and installing one of these units was one of our favorite kitchen improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Another use is an air pressure switch for a garbage disposal/food grinder. When we moved in it took a while to discover that using the garbage disposal required opening the cupboard door and reaching underneath the sink for a switch. When we too went from three fittings to one I got the chance to install an air pressure switch in one of the spare holes. (A soap dispenser went in the other hole.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hole for a sprayer attachement.

Answer (score 0):

Brizo (subsidiary of Delta Faucet company) makes a towel holder or a small flower vase (weird right?!) Other than that its either a hole cover, soap dispenser, filtered water tap, or instant hot.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We usually discourage product-oriented links; there's enough information to help the OP in what I left.

Comment: Those are a few new products I hadn’t heard of, thanks @Dan!